# ¿Qué palabras se ocultan en las rimas de la canción "Las tretas de Lorena"?

Tags: letras-de-canciones, vulgaridades, chile, humor

En una canción del cantante chileno Felo llamada [*Las tretas de Lorena*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLQLoHguco8) se busca hacer un conjunto de rimas picarescas. El objetivo es un juego de palabras con un [doble sentido en las rimas](http://www.albumcancionyletra.com/las-tretas-de-lorena_de_felo___43288.aspx), aunque algunas están con chilenismos, lo que evita que se pueda entender para todo el resto del mundo hispano.

En particular, son cuatro los versos cuya rima no alcanzo a entender y me gustaría saber cuáles serían las palabras 'originales' (las malas palabras ocultas en la canción)

> No sé qué me pasa, que estoy como loco
>   me duele el alma, me duelen los... ojos (...)
>   (...) Cuando te marchaste mi ser quedó roto
>   yo anhelo tus manos, tus labios, tu... rostro (...)
>   (...) Para demostrar que sin ti mi alma es nula
>   te ofrezco entera toda mi... fortuna (...)
>   (...) Cuando pasa el tiempo que todo lo borra
>   ya no seguiré persiguiendo tu... sombra (...)

Comment: Ya el título tiene su ambigüedad estudiada, ¡está muy divertido el audio! Cada rima tiene su aquél.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que las palabras escondidas son:

> No se que me pasa, que estoy como loco
>   me duele el alma, me duelen los [**<s>cocos</s>**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coco#Spanish)... ojos.
>   De tanto llorar como si fuera un nene
>   aunque tu estes lejos te llevo en mi <s>pene</s>... mente.
>   Cuando te marchaste mi ser quedo roto,
>   yo anhelo tus manos, tus labios, tu [**<s>poto</s>**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/poto#Spanish)... rostro.
>   Espero que un dia tu alma inquieta
>   te haga regresar y descubras tus <s>tetas</s>... tretas.
>
> Supieras tu cuanto te he echado de menos,
>   quiero acariciarte y besarte los <s>senos</s>... dedos.
>   Y duermo pensando en tiempos mejores
>   cuando sonreían tus labios <s>menores</s>... cantores.
>
> Presiento que al irte mi vida te llevas
>   no se que decirte, tengo [mala <s>cuea</s>](http://diccionariochileno.cl/term/Mala+cuea)... estrella.
>   Mi llanto postrero dejo en mi canción,
>   si ya te perdi fue solo de... [<s>weón</s>](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/we%C3%B3n#Spanish) cepción (decepción).
>
> Para demostrar que sin ti mi alma es nula,
>   te ofrezco entera toda mi [**<s>tula</s>**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tula#Spanish)... fortuna.
>   Aunque ya no pueda darte cosas nuevas,
>   por ti soy capaz de cortarme las [<s>weas</s>](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Weas.php)... venas.
>
> Desde que te fuiste mi alma no encaja,
>   el golpe tremendo de no ver tu <s>raja</s>... cara.
>   Y solo en mi cuarto mirando el techo,
>   abrazo mi almohada pensando en tu <s>pecho</s>... pelo.
>   Solo hay un con suelo pa' mi pena eterna
>   el ser el primero al que abriste tus <s>piernas</s>... senda.
>   Cuando pasa el tiempo que todo lo borra,
>   ya no seguiré persiguiendo tu **<s>[zorra](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=zorra)</s>**... sombra.
>
> Tal vez para entonces tu me causes risa,
>   me dará lo mismo si otro hombre te [<s>pisa</s>](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Pisar.php)... mira.
>   Y cuando mi amor, mi cariño se pierda
>   podre al fin decirte: andate... <s>a la mierda</s>... y no vuelvas.

Puedes descubrir más canciones humorísticas etc chilenas así aquí:

[*Una taxonomía de los actos humorísticos*](http://repositorio.uchile.cl/bitstream/handle/2250/132777/Una-taxonomia-de-los-actos-humoristicos.pdf?sequence=1), Clotilde Vivanco Torres et al. (Universidad de Chile)

Comment: gracias, los 4 versos me quedan claros (los demás se facilitan creo que para casi todo el mundo hispano)